# Is it possible to build/simulate/extract data from a System Modeler model completely inside a notebook using the MathModelica language syntax?

Tags: programming, system-modeler

See examples in:
http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/contents/MathModelicaPaper/MathModelicaPaper_2.html

It seems to be ruled out by the statement (Chapter 2 intro):
"The subset of the Modelica language described in this section can be used in the simulation models, not in general Mathematica programming."

but I just want to make sure I understand what this is saying, for example, does "simulation models" refer to SystemModeler only, or to simulating from within a notebook using WSMLink?

Answer (score 2):

The MathModelica syntax in the linked paper is obsoleted and not supported by SystemModeler.

- To create and modify models in SystemModeler from a notebook, use the
  functions `WSMCreateModel`, `WSMConnectComponents`,
  `WSMCreateModelString`, `WSMConnectComponentsString` and
  `WSMSetValues`.
- To simulate use the functions `WSMSimulate` and
  `WSMSimulateSensitivity`.
- To extract data about the model use `WSMModelData`.

  All of these functions are linked from the [guide page](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/WSMLink/guide/WSMLink.html).